# Dead area on monitor, can I re-adjust screen 0,0 point?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, resolution, dell-inspiron

I'm using Windows 7 Professional on Dell Inspiron N5110.

I'm having problem with my laptop LCD screen.

About 1cm of my monitor is white on the left side. Due to which Windows start button is hidden, the back navigation button of the chrome is hidden and some other details too.

Is there any way I can adjust the top left corner of my display to be more toward the right?
I know it will make my screen a bitter narrower, but I'm OK with that.

Comment: If you have an onboard Intel Graphics chipset, you could try the "Custom Resolutions" feature (right click on the desktop -> Graphics Options -> Custom Resolutions) and set an appropriate height, width and [underscan](http://www.themacfaq.com/2010/11/11/understand-overscan-and-underscan/) percentage. However this might be a risky thing to do (Intel warns it might reduce system stability, may cause chipset to fail, etc.)

Comment: I used different solution though, I moved the Taskbar to the right and changed its hight to cover the blind area :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you choose to use the "custom resolution" method, you might want to add an answer to your question outlining what you did and the settings you used so others with the same problem know what to do.